# Web Component: Accessing the shadow DOM within the Custom Component class

Tags: javascript, web-component, web-component-tester, google-web-component, native-web-component

With this project, I'm trying to create a custom component that will behave as a map. I'm still learning the fundamentals of Web Components through the W3C documentation and several Youtube videos.

The main question is, in the component class there's to be a function called `attributeChangedCallback()` that will be triggered every time one of the attributes change, these attributes are included in the `observedAttributes()` function and after setting them up (the previously mentioned function) I try to access the shadow DOM( that is declared `connectedCallback()` that will be triggered once the component is loaded in the HTML body element) through a selector. However, the variable content is null if I do it.

The `attributeChangedCallback()` should be loaded *AFTER* the content is loaded so I don't understand why this is happening and I need to access to this element every time the attributes change so I can update its content. Curious fact: if I log every time the `attributeChangedCallback()` is executed it log twice (because I have two attributes being watched).

Here's the snippet:

```js
class GeoComponent extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
  this._latitude = 0;
  this._longitude = 0;
 }

 get latitude(){
  return this._latitude;
 }

 get longitude(){
  return this._longitude;
 }

 set latitude(val){
  this.setAttribute('latitude', val);
 }

 set longitude(val){
  this.setAttribute('longitude', val);
 }

 static get observedAttributes(){
  return ['latitude', 'longitude'];
 }
 
 attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal){
  let geoComp = this.shadow.getElementById('geo');
  console.log(geoComp);
  switch(name){
   case 'latitude':
    this._latitude = parseInt(newVal, 0) || 0;
    // geoComp.innerHTML = `${this.latitude}, ${this.longitude}`;
    break;
   case 'longitude':
    this._longitude = parseInt(newVal, 0) || 0;
    // geoComp.innerHTML = `${this.latitude}, ${this.longitude}`;
    break
  }
 }

 connectedCallback(){
  let template = `
   <div class="geo-component" id="geo">
    
   </div>
  `;

  this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
 }
}

window.customElements.define('geo-component', GeoComponent);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="geoComponent.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Geo-Component</h1>
 <geo-component latitude="12" longitude="-70"></geo-component>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Just like @acdcjunior mentioned after changing `this.createShadowRoot();` to `this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});` (going from ShadowDOM v0 to v1) solved my problem given that the `connectedCallback()` function is executed behind scenes and only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attributeChangedCallback()` is called when an (observed) attribute is **initialized (declaratively, which is your case)**, added, changed or removed. Which means it is called before `connectedCallback()`.

Typically we use the constructor() to create the DOM:

> *Name:* **constructor**
>   *Called when:* An instance of the element is created
>   or upgraded. Useful for initializing state, settings up event
>   listeners, or **creating shadow dom**. See the spec for restrictions on
>   what you can do in the constructor.

I moved your logic to it.

Also you are using ShadowDOM v0. Updated it to v1 (`attachShadow` instead of `createShadowRoot`).

Updated demo:

```js
class GeoComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('constructor called');
    
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this._latitude = 0;
    this._longitude = 0;
    
    let template = `
   <div class="geo-component" id="geo">

   </div>
  `;
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
  }

  get latitude() {
    return this._latitude;
  }

  get longitude() {
    return this._longitude;
  }

  set latitude(val) {
    this.setAttribute('latitude', val);
  }

  set longitude(val) {
    this.setAttribute('longitude', val);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['latitude', 'longitude'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('attributeChangedCallback() called:', name, ':', oldVal, '->', newVal);

    let geoComp = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('geo');
    console.log(geoComp);
    
    switch (name) {
      case 'latitude':
        this._latitude = parseInt(newVal, 0) || 0;
        // geoComp.innerHTML = `${this.latitude}, ${this.longitude}`;
        break;
      case 'longitude':
        this._longitude = parseInt(newVal, 0) || 0;
        // geoComp.innerHTML = `${this.latitude}, ${this.longitude}`;
        break
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connectedCallback() called');
  }
}

window.customElements.define('geo-component', GeoComponent);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="geoComponent.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Geo-Component</h1>
  <geo-component latitude="12" longitude="-70"></geo-component>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware I was using an old version of ShadowDOM. This solved my problem thanks.

Comment: You can access the `shadowRoot` on the element itself, i.e. `this.shadowRoot`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot

Comment: @holmberd This must be something new, yes?

Comment: @holmberd Very well, not that new, then. I have added it to the answer. Thanks a lot.